# Using a dynamic variable for the key of an object literal

Tags: javascript

I have a series of variables that I would like to pass into an object and I need the left side key to be pulled from a dynamic variable. How would I go about doing this?

Here's an example:

```js
var characteristic = 'color';
var value = 'green';

// Desired JSON output
var object = {
  color: 'green'
}
```

Comment: Please tag the appropriate programming language you need this in?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/218196)

Answer (score 0):

like so:

```js
var characteristic = 'color';
var value = 'green';

var object = {
  [characteristic]: value
}

console.log(object);
```